# Pycharm - Cannot find reference 'keys' in 'int|float|complex'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

In Pycharm I get `Cannot find reference 'keys' in 'int|float|complex'`  and `Cannot find reference '[' in 'int|float|complex'` for the following lines. How can I fix it? I insist to fix it!

```
dictionary = np.load(path2sink + 'dict.npy').item()
keys = [k for k in dictionary.keys() if dictionary[k] < threshold]
```

Comment: What's the type and value of `dictionary`? Have a look using the debugger.

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to:

`dictionary = np.load(path2sink + 'dict.npy').items()` instead?

Comment: @F.Leone I want to retrieve the dictionary I saved before.

Answer (score -1):

`dictionary = np.load(path2sink + 'dict.npy')[()]`，this code will not show "Cannot find reference keys int| float|complex" in pycharm.

Comment: `.item()` is similiar to `[()]` . not sure why the problem would be solved because of the change

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: in my pycharm, .item()  will show "Cannot find reference keys int| float|complex", but [()] all is ok.